# Parsing through object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have this object and I want to get the portalname.
How would I do that, using JS or jQuery

**OBJECT**

```
var Test = {};

Test.Customers = [{"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"1","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"11","test":"4251","portalname":"tye.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"12","test":"4251","portalname":"Lsdf.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"13","test":"4251","portalname":"nick.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"2","customer":"1952","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"14","test":"4252","portalname":"Chrysanthemum2.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"15","test":"4255","portalname":"navagin.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"16","test":"4257","portalname":"jasoria.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    },
                    {"CustomerItems":
                            "Portals":
                            {"id":"3","customer":"1950","resident":"yes",
                            "CustomPortals":
                                        [
                                        {"id":"17","test":"4231","portalname":"Zsryanmum1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"18","test":"4651","portalname":"Ltd1.jpg"},
                                         {"id":"19","test":"4281","portalname":"ser1.jpg"}
                                         ]
                            }
                    }
                ]
```

**TRIED**

```
 $.each(Test.Customers, function(index, value) {

                $.each(value.CustomPortals, function(innerIndex, innerValue) {
                    alert('File ' + innerValue + ' in customer ' + innerIndex);
                });

            });
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner ".each()" loop needs to traverse "CustomerItems.Portals" to get to "CustomPortals":

```
            $.each(value.CustomerItems.Portals.CustomPortals, function(innerIndex, innerValue) {
                alert('File ' + innerValue + ' in customer ' + innerIndex);
            });
```

It'd probably be a good idea to add some existence tests, but you know your data better than I do.

*edit* — @justkt has a really good point - that JSON is, as posted here, not valid in the first place. Thus what I wrote above would be true **if** the stuff could be parsed :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
alert('File ' + innerValue.portalname + ' in customer ' + innervalue.id);
```

instead of

```
alert('File ' + innerValue + ' in customer ' + innerIndex);
```

Answer (score 2):

When I ran your object through JSONLint (while I know that JSON is stricter than JS objects, it is an easy validator), it complained about this syntax:

```
"CustomerItems" : "Portals" : {}
```

By removing the "Portals" and instead setting:

```
"CustomerItems" : {}
```

and using the JS below:

```
$.each(Test.Customers, function(index, value) {

    $.each(value.CustomerItems.CustomPortals, function(innerIndex, innerValue) {
        alert('File ' + innerValue.portalname + ' in customer ' + innerValue.id);
    });

});
```

I was able to get a working iterator that you can see in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QM8cA/).